# Android - Can you explain why you can remove the code?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working with a online video curses about Android.

I have a list of items and when I click on a list item opens a new activity to show the details of the item. The problem is that I get a double text on detail activity which I try to fix it and I figure out that if I remove the code on DetailsActivity#onCreate()

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.details_fragment, new DetailsActivityFragment())
          .commit();
}
```

the detail activity displayed fine.

Here is the photos and the code of DetailsActivity (working with fragment in different class)

Main Activity

[image: main activity]

Details Activity

[image: Details Activity]

But if I comment out the part of code which I mention below on DetailsActivity#onCreate(), the detail activity looks fine:

after comment out the code

[image: after comment out the code]

DetailsActivity.java:

```
import android...//all the need package here don't worry about

public class DetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private  Intent shareIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        //Create my Share Intent (for share  options in action bar)
        shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My whether data");
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    /* IF I COMMENT THIS if CODE details showed fine. No double text */
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.details_fragment, new DetailsActivityFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_details, menu);

        //Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider OR find the MenuItem that we know has the ShareActionProvider
        MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share_item);

        // Fetch and Store ShareActionProvider
        ShareActionProvider MyShareProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        if(MyShareProvider != null){
            MyShareProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
            Log.d(DetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "INTO share Provider--" + MyShareProvider.toString());
        }
        else{
            Log.d(DetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "NO share Provider");
        }

        return true;
     }

....other code...
}
```

and I have implement the fragment in another class

```
public class DetailsActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailsActivityFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //get the view of fragment's layout
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        //get Extras form intent
        Bundle DataFromIntent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();

        //get specific data as String.
        String weatherDataDetails = DataFromIntent.getString("weatherDataDetails");

        //get text view from layout (rootview) and set test on it the above data (whetherData)
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.details_textview)).setText(weatherDataDetails);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

My layouts (main + fragment)

activity_details.xml (main)

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/details_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailsActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and fragment_details.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailsActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="---null---"
        android:id = "@+id/details_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your layout activity_details.xml?

Comment: sure I will update my post right now!

Comment: @DerekFung I update my post, thanks for your interest

Comment: Obviously because fragment is in layout... Use official android's guide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that it used a `<fragment>` tag here

With `<fragment>` tag, the fragment is attached automatically when the layout is created. I.e. it is almost like the code below is automatically run for you

```
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.details_fragment, new DetailsActivityFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
```

So if you run the code by yourself, it would be like creating ANOTHER fragment and put it on the same spot. It should be why you see that strange behaviour.

**Edit:**
In general, we handle fragments in one of the follow 2 ways

1. define in `<fragment>` tag and do NOT use FragmentManager to manage it
   in code afterwards.
2. we declare a container, usually an empty `<FrameLayout>` and we use FragmentManager like the code above to manage it in code.

P.S. of course there are other cases you use ViewPager etc, but you will know later when you need it.

Reference:

Using `<fragment>` tag
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Using container
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: one last question: So in my layout I create two fragments, that's why I get two texts on details activity?

Comment: I think so. Actually that is a very strange case, because normally we would not do that.